# How can I know what touchpad do I have if now it's being recognized as Generic wheel mouse?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, mouse, touchpad

So... I bought this chinese laptop (cheap copy of a mac air) and everything seems to work fine except for the touchpad. 
It has this buggy sidescrolling, which doesn't please me too much.

So I'm trying to figure out what hardware is it so i can install some drivers.

When i run

> xinput

```
j$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

when I run

> cat /proc/bus/input/devices

```
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0005 Version=0000
N: Name="ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input6
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event11 
B: PROP=1
B: EV=7
B: KEY=70000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=103
```

when I run

> dmesg | grep -i mouse

```
[    1.551256] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    3.314465] input: ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input6
```

when I run

> dmesg | grep -i i8042

```
[    1.535050] i8042: PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:PS2K,PNP0f13:PS2M] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1,12
[    1.550998] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[    1.551002] serio: i8042 AUX port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12
[    1.566761] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4
[    3.314465] input: ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input6
```

Is there anyway to know what touchpad do I have? I have tried contacting the manufacturer but they don't answer me back...

Thank you!

Comment: Does it show up in `lsusb`?

Comment: No, it doesn't :(